# How to approach sorting array largest value first everything else ascending

Tags: java, sorting

After generating random numbers in previously user initialised array size afterwards it should be sorted as: Largest value first, everything else in ascending order.

INPUT: 8 29 15 52 18
OUTPUT: 52 8 15 18 29

The problem is I can not understand rather it should be used via one sorting algorithm or via two and then combining? Without Arrays.sort. method.

Did some code for input, random value generating, and finding the largest value and displayig it.

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Ievadiet masiva lielumu: "); //Enter array size
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        Random valuesGenerator = new Random();

        int num = scan.nextInt();
        int[] myArray = new int[num];

        for (int i = 0; i < myArray.length; ++i) {
            int randomInt = valuesGenerator.nextInt(100);
            myArray[i] = randomInt;
        }

        System.out.println("Randomizeti generetais masivs: "); //Generated array

        for(int k=0; k < myArray.length; k++)
        {
            System.out.print(myArray[k] + " ");
        }

        System.out.println(); //New line

        int largest = myArray[0];

        int largeIndx = 0;

        for (int i = 1; i < myArray.length; i++) {
            if (myArray[i] > largest) {
                largest = myArray[i];
                largeIndx = i;
            }
        }

        System.out.println("===================");
        System.out.println("Largest value = "+largest);
        System.out.println("Largest value index = "+largeIndx);
        System.out.println("First element is = "+myArray[0]); //first
        System.out.println("");

        for(int k=0; k < myArray.length; k++)
        {
            System.out.print(myArray[k] + " ");
        }
    }
```

Comment: You can read more about sorting algorithms here: https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~adamchik/15-121/lectures/Sorting%20Algorithms/sorting.html

Answer (score 0):

The way I would do that would probably be to find the largest value (you got that already), swap it with the first element in the array and then apply any sorting algorithm on the array, excluding the first element.